# Module menu item doesnt work

Tags: uri, routes

I have a menu item in my module like this

```
$item['imageuploadsuccess'] = array(
    'title' => 'Upload Image Success',
    'page callback' => 'image_success',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM
);
```

and the callback looks like this

```
function image_success(){
$page = '<p>'.t('You successfully uploaded your image.').'</p>';
return $page;
```

}

When I go to /imageuploadsuccess, I get told that the page doesn't exist. I've tried clearing my cache completely and I still get nothing. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Clear drupal cache : Configuration - Performance - Clear cache

Comment: @inizio I've done that, no change.

Comment: Have you returned `$item` from `hook_menu()`?

Comment: @Clive Ah that was it! All my other menu items were $items, not $item. Thank you!